# Is this artwork (used in a video game) real?

Tags: identification, art

In *Phantasmagoria* video game you can find an artwork (most probably a tapestry) that looks like real piece of art and not something made for the game.

I've done some research, but I wasn't able to find any information regarding it.

Would someone be able to identify it?

Unfortunately it's the best quality I could get.

[image]

Comment: Does the game give any hints about location or time period?

Comment: @SteveBird The game events take place in a 19th-century mansion in New England. I don't think there is any information provided regarding the artwork itself.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Google image search brings this up pretty easily.  (Image recognition technology is amazing these days.)  It is [The Abduction of Orithyia by Boreas](https://art.famsf.org/rene-antoine-houasse/abduction-orithyia-boreas-metamorphoses-ovid-series-19484), a late 17th century tapestry.

[image: The Abduction of Orithyia by Boreas,]

I gather it's currently in storage at a San Francisco museum rather than at a New England mansion.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Interestingly, I tried image search, but on a different side and it didn't find it.

Comment: _Google image search brings this up pretty easily._ . Did you search with this screenshot directly or did you crop the artwork and transform/stretch it back to a rectangular shape?

Comment: I literally just threw the stack overflow image URL (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDflB.png) into the search bar.  I honestly didn't expect that to work.   Amusingly, google image search now points to this question/answer. :-P

Comment: I'm mildly disappointed to learn it's not currently hanging in Roberta William's sitting room.

Comment: Wow, reverse image searches got scary real fast.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Whoah!  would have expected one would at least need to un-perspective the image ...

Comment: I feel somewhat guilty that what is now my second highest voted answer on the entire stack exchange network was the results of 30 seconds research done on a lark.

Comment: This is also very scary for privacy... if someone has a pic of your face taken in the street, with a simple google reverse-image search, they could know your name and everything else about you.